# Wiring circuit breaker directly to telephone pole?

Tags: wiring

I want to add an 30 amp RV connection to the telephone pole where my power comes in.

I've wired outlets before, but always by attaching to my main circuit breaker box. But this RV outlet isn't going to go through the circuit breaker box. It's an exterior box that'll contain its own circuit breaker, a 30 amp outlet, and likely a 20 amp outlet.

(Note: it won't bypass the electrical meter, obviously, as that'd be illegal, and my electrical meter has a power cutoff, so I can kill power before wiring up my box)

I haven't ordered one yet, but something like this:
[image]

I have two questions:

1. Can I just wire a circuit breaker directly into the powerline running out of the electrical meter?

I never wired up a new circuit breaker box before, so I don't know if circuit breaker boxes contain any electrical component between the power from the meter and individual circuit breakers.

2. What do I do for ground? I assume what's coming off the telephone pole is two phases and a common. Do I just drive a copper grounding rod anywhere into the dirt to ground my RV outlet?

Comment: A picture and model number of meter cabinet, model of added panel, and your location would go a long way to eliminating variables.

Comment: Is this power pole dedicated to you, if the transmission lines are connected to this pole the answer is always no you can not attach to the pole you could check with the utility but my experience in a few states if the transmission lines come to the pole and go to another it is off limits. If the pole is on your property and only the service drop is there with the existing meter normally you can add a box below. But if a utility owned pole they have the control (code will allow the box to be mounted on the pole).

Comment: @EdBeal Yes, if owned by the landowner. But we can't forget about how he's going to connect it. Does his meter base have extra lugs?   Unusual if it does. May have to fit a lug kit to provide extra connections. Also, the OP will need to follow the "tap rules" as listed here, which are complicated:  https://library.e.abb.com/public/9e7ae3c8094341488549ef5a3e791064/ABB-1742-WPO_NEC_Tap_Rules.pdf

Actually, not sure of that. With no overcurrent protection bc coming directly off the meter base, I dk how that could be calculated.

Comment: Does your house currently have an outdoor main disconnect?

Comment: @george Anderson the 10’ tap rule can be used here no breaker at the source  1/10 of a 200 amp service is 20 amp. so ok for most homes on the 20 amp but we also have the 30 so it would be almost balanced . If we need split bolts are quite common in a case like this if you cannot change a single chair to a double.,  I would probably spend a couple more $ and put in a full service RV pedestal with 50a 240v 30a 120 and 20 amp 120v receptacles I was getting some nice ones on line last year for ~110$  China virus put the brakes on that job but we may restart in the spring if they can open this year

Comment: George, I just noticed your link, use the code book not near as long 240.22.B.1  I always remember 10’ is 1/10 or more not much to think of  in this case 30 amp only could be done with #10 wire in conduit, jump to a 50 amp pedestals and you now have 240 out there for not much more.

Comment: Can you post photos of your existing metering arrangement please? Also,. who's your electric utility?